# Would the Earth form a black hole if time stopped?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time

> The effect of time dilation in a black hole is caused by the movement from a high gravitational potential to a lower one. It is predicted by relativity, but impossible to prove empirically since we cannot go in and out of a black hole at will. It is only the observer within the hole for which time stops, though.
>   If one would be inside a black hole, a day would still last a day. However the time outside that black hole would have passed at a much higher rate. Would one be truly at the center of a black hole where gravity is infinite, then time would stop compared to the world outside the black hole.

My question is, is the opposite possible, I.e., if time stops in Earth, would the gravitational pull become so strong that it would form a singularity? Can this be proven using GR?

Comment: Of course physically, it's neither plausible or possible, just asking what would the theoretical predictions be? Just wondering if the opposite(of time stopping in the singularity) is possible or not...

Comment: *"Of course physically, it's neither plausible or possible, just asking what would the theoretical predictions be?"* - I don't understand the reasoning here; if X is not possible according to theory A, and then one stipulates that X is the case, why would one look to theory A for a prediction?

Comment: Now, I completely understand that you don't have the same experience with advanced physics that many of us do and that this may seem, at first glance, to be a perfectly reasonable question. I don't judge you harshly for asking it; it makes sense that you'd think we can answer it. However, I cannot answer this question. In fact, it is not really a question that makes sense to a physicist. It's going to sound like I'm being insulting, but I'm not. This question to us is much like asking "If cheese were made of honey, would bees grow and become big bee-cows?"

Comment: How do you approach that question from a scientific point of view? I don't know. I'm not trying to be aloof or insulting; I know the current situation is not as obvious as the one I likened it to, but I'm just trying to give you insight into how that question translates into non-physics speech. It sounds reasonable to someone who has little experience in advanced physics, but it's baffling to us how we'd even approach it other than to just point out where there appears to be misconceptions

Comment: @Jim I'm no physicist like you, I'm just a student trying to learn and understand the new things that I encounter. If its a just a really wrong question, then why not just tell that to me cause I'm a student and no physicist;I'm aware that this question would get me quite a few down votes, just asked the question because I needed help understanding it. And yeah sure what you said was neither insulting nor judgmental! Now that I'm told that this is a BS question, I'll go ahead and vote to close my own question.

Comment: See this is the problem with written words, lack of tone of voice. I do seriously understand that it's not an obvious thing that this question makes no sense. I've been there before. I've also, as you suggested, tried to explain to people why it doesn't make sense without using examples. It almost invariably doesn't work. I'm not judging or attempting to insult. I only wanted to illustrate how we couldn't approach the question, which is why you likely won't find much in the way of detailed answers.

Comment: My example seems like a stupid question (to be brutally frank). It is, in fact, an extremely stupid question. Why? Because everyone is familiar with the subject matter. Very few people are familiar with advanced physics. So, while the form and function of both your question and my example are similar, yours was not a stupid question because it covers such an esoteric subject, whereas my example is stupid because of it's simplicity. The stupidity of mine should not be transferred to yours. I'm not attempting to insult

Comment: This has been put on hold so I won't bother with a real answer. Also, it is not a well posed question. But if I interpret your question as saying: if in some hyper surface of spacetime time, as seen by an outside observer at infinity in asymptotically flat spacetime, slows down infinitely (I.e., your statement 'time stops'), that hyper-surface would be a causal horizon, or a singularity, according to GR. Is that true? It is certainly true for a hypersurface in a Schwarzschild solution/geometry, and maybe for Kerr. Maybe it is always true, maybe by definition, not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only known way to increase gravitational time dilation is to increase the gravity, and so increase the mass.  This doesn't seem to fit with your question.

There's a couple ideas that you seem to be mixed up on.

Time dilation is always something you see someone else do.  Either someone is moving by you and you see their time as ticking along slower.  Or someone is lower in a gravitational well and then you also see their clock ticking slower.

But your clock always ticks along at the ordinary speed for you.  In science fiction, sometimes people are 'trapped in slow time' and notice themselves moving in slow motion.  This could never happen.  Ever.  Your perception is based on biology, which is based on chemical processes which click along with every other clock.

Black holes don't have infinite gravity.  There might be some funny business when you approach the singularity (quantum gravity should become significant as you fall towards the singularity, and no one really knows what quantum gravity will be like yet), but gravity levels are finite all the way down.